# Choosing correct tense for dependent clauses when casting a present-tense statement into past

Tags: grammar, past-tense

Putting present-simple statements in the past is my pain. In particular, I always stumble upon which tense to chose for dependent clauses:

> Right now the teacher is asking students one by one some similar questions and they
>   are answering them one by one while Johnny is following them precisely -
>   in order to to know how to answer properly when it's his turn.

If I try to put it in the past I get the following:

> At that moment the teacher was asking students one by one some similar
>   questions and they were answering them one by one while Johnny was
>   following them precisely - in order to know how to answer properly
>   when **it was his turn**.

Do I need to say here **when it was his turn**, or **when it would be his turn**, or **when it would have been his turn**? Or should I say something completely different?

Comment: Where is the relative clause that you talk of?

Comment: @BillJ - "when it was his turn"

Comment: That's not a relative clause, it's an adjunct of time.

Comment: "When" is not a relative word here - it has no antecedent. But to answer your question "was" is fine.

Comment: @BillJ - Ah! I see. I'll change the title.